# Return observable <Type> from nested REST response

Tags: angular, rest, http

I am just getting started with Angular and its the first time I work with observables. I have gone through the Tours of Heroes tutorial on the official website and want to translate it into my application.

hero.service.ts from the tutorial has the following function:

```
/** GET heroes from the server */
getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
  return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
    .pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log('fetched heroes')),
      catchError(this.handleError<Hero[]>('getHeroes', []))
    );
}
```

I can get it to work when JSON response looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user": "admin",
        "date": "2020-12-03T12:25:11Z",
        "name": "Test"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "user": "admin",
        "date": "2020-12-03T13:34:01Z",
        "name": "Test2"
    }
]
```

But my REST API returns the following:

```
    {
    "count": 6,
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/heroes?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "user": "admin",
            "date": "2020-12-03T12:25:11Z",
            "name": "Test"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "user": "admin",
            "date": "2020-12-03T13:34:01Z",
            "name": "Test2"
        }
    ]
}
```

So my question is, how can I transform the response to extract the data from the nested results field?

I assume I have to save the response from this.http.get(this.heroesUrl) (without <Hero[]>) and then extract the 'results' section and return the observable?

Answer (score 1):

```
getHeroes().subscribe(res=>{
    
   let data = res.results;
});
```

or you can use RxJs map

```
getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
   return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
    .pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log('fetched heroes')),
      map( data=>{
          let val = data.results;
          return val;
       }),
      catchError(this.handleError<Hero[]>('getHeroes', []))
    );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

change `Observable<Hero[]>` to `Observable<HttpResponse<Hero[]>>` in service file and subscriber as,

```js
data: Array<Hero>;
getHeroes().subscribe(res=>{
   this.data = res.results;
});
```